# Changing the props of onChange in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I use this dropdown component by Semantic UI, it has an `onChange` method that updates the value of the selection, usually, it works like `onChange={this.pickIcon}` and then you can access the value

```
pickIcon = (e, { value}) => {
  console.log(value)
  // console.log(item)
}
```

My situation here is a bit different I got a list with array map, each with a single dropdown, I need the value of each array item so I can save the data, getting only the selected icon does not help, can please someone assist with that?

I tried adding the prop manually but it crash and I cannot log both values as it throw this error

```
onChange={(item) => this.pickIcon(item)}
```

> Cannot destructure property 'value' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

This is my full code to give you a better context

```
const menuIcons = this.state.screens.map((item, index) => (
  <Grid.Row key={index}>
    <Grid.Column width="6">{item.name}</Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column width="10">
      <h4>{selectedIcon}</h4>
      <Dropdown
        fluid
        onChange={item => this.pickIcon(item)}
        options={iconsList}
        placeholder="Pick Icon"
        selection
        search
        value={selectedIcon}
      />
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid.Row>
));
```

My goal is to pass either `item` or `index` to the function

Answer (score 1):

The first `param` is always recognized as an Event `e`

So here `item` is recognized as an item and hence you cant seem to make it work as the function accepts two params.

Try this

```
pickIcon = (e, value) => {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(value)
  }
```

```
onChange={(e) => this.pickIcon(e,item)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pickIcon function takes two parameters, (e, {value}). So you should be passing 2 arguments to it or you should change your pickIcon function to accept single argument.

Your onChange will give you `event` object. so call your pickIcon like below provided you are interested in event object -

```
onChange={(event) => this.pickIcon(event, item)}
```

If you are not interested in `event` object use below -

```
onChange={() => this.pickIcon(item)}

pickIcon = (item) => {
  console.log(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **item** from function

```
  <Dropdown
    fluid
    onChange={() => this.pickIcon(item)} // Here remove item and pass from map
    options={iconsList}
    placeholder='Pick Icon'
    selection
    search
    value={selectedIcon}
  />
```

Also you are passing only item please remove **event**

```
  pickIcon = ({ value }) => { // Remove e
    console.log(value)
    // console.log(item)
  }
```

Comment: That's what I tried first it's not working, when I do it inline it returns this Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchListeners: Array(2), _dispatchInstances: Array(2), nativeEvent: MouseEvent, …}

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this code

```
 pickIcon = (itemdata) => {
    console.log(itemdata)
    // console.log(item)
  }
```

when you call function without param it will automatically pass event (e) and the value so you got it right the first time

Now you are passing one param so you should receive with one param only

Answer (score 0):

All answers only focus on a single param I need both of them, anyway I figured this out

```
  onChange={(e, value) => this.pickIcon(item, e, value)}

  pickIcon = (item, e, value) => {
        console.log(item)
        console.log(value)
      }
```